# Difference between two recursive functions

Tags: javascript

**findElementById**

```
function findElementRecursion (inputId, currentElement) {
    if (currentElement.id == inputId) {
        return true;
    }
    var numChildren = currentElement.children.length;
    if (numChildren > 0) {
        for (i=0; i<numChildren; i++) {
            var currentChild = currentElement.children[i];
            console.log(currentChild);
            return findElementRecursion(inputId, currentChild);
        }
    }   
    return false;
}
```

Would anyone help me debug this recursive function?
It returns false when it should return true. Since I don't see any error message, I am having a hard time trying to figure out what's the problem. It would be helpful if someone told me the steps of debugging this kind of problem.

**update:**
the problem was that I was returning only after inspecting the first child of currentElement. I fixed that problem but the function still returns false when it should return true.

```
function findElementRecursion (inputId, currentElement) {
    if (currentElement.id == inputId) {
        return true;
    }
    var numChildren = currentElement.children.length;
    if (numChildren > 0) {
        for (i=0; i<numChildren; i++) {
            var currentChild = currentElement.children[i];
            if (findElementRecursion(inputId, currentChild)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }   
    return false;
}
```

Try this from console on this page with `findElementRecursion (`mainbar`, document)` and you will see `false`.

Comment: For one thing you're breaking your for loop early by returning too early - `return findElementRecursion(inputId, currentChild);`

Comment: Given the name of the function, if the element is found, wouldn't it be better to return the element, not `true`?

Comment: yes actually you're right @Robg :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function findElementRecursion (inputId, currentElement) {
    var result = false;
    if (currentElement.id == inputId) {
        return true;
    }
    for (var i=0; i<currentElement.children.length; i++) {
        var currentChild = currentElement.children[i];
        console.log(currentChild);
        result = findElementRecursion(inputId, currentChild);

        // we can break here
        if(result)
             return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how it works differently from the given code. Could you explain the difference?

Comment: @MaximusS - the code is only breaking out of the for loop (by returning a result) if the result is true (i.e. found).  Otherwise it continues looking @ the other children.  In your code, you are returning on the first child even if false.

Comment: Unfortunately, there seem to be more bugs to the code. It still returns false when it should return true.

Comment: @Maximus—in your code, it is only traversing the first child of each node, it doesn't get to a second. Also, the *children* property is not part of the W3C DOM specs (AFAIK) and may not be supported by all browsers in use.

Comment: @RobG I think there's still a problem with the recursive(besides returning too early)function because an iterative function that uses children property returns the right value.

Answer (score 1):

If I was going to do this, I wouldn't use a recursive function, I'd just use *getElementsByTagName*. It would be faster and traverse elements in the same order. It will also only visit elements, whereas other methods may visit text nodes too.

```
function findElementById(id, root) {
  root = root || document;
  var elements = root.getElementsByTagName('*');

  for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if (elements[i].id == id) {
      return elements[i];
    }
  }
}
```

But maybe you just want a recursive function for the exercise.

```
function findElementByIdRecursive(id, element) {

  // If no element passed in, use document
  element = element || document;

  // If element has id, return it
  if (element.id == id) return element;

  // Otherwise, keep going
  var foundElement;
  var childNodes = element.childNodes;

  // Not needed on modern browsers but older browsers may throw an error
  // if the node can't have children (like a text node)
  if (childNodes) {

    // Only keep looping while a matching element isn't found    
    for (var i=0,iLen=childNodes.length; i<iLen  && !foundElement; i++) {

      // Save a call if this node matches    
      if (childNodes[i].id == id) {
        return childNodes[i];
      }

      // Otherwise, go down its children
      foundElement = findElementByIdRecursive(id, childNodes[i]);
    }
    return foundElement;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you break the loop early:

```
    function findElementRecursion (inputId, currentElement) {
        var result = false;
        if (currentElement.id == inputId) {
            return true;
        }
        var numChildren = currentElement.children.length;
        if (numChildren > 0) {
            for (i=0; i<numChildren; i++) {
                var currentChild = currentElement.children[i];
                console.log(currentChild);
                result = findElementRecursion(inputId, currentChild);
                if(result){
                   break;
                   }
            }
        }   
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This will always return false unless the first element has the inputId

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways to do this - like using jQuery - but this should work:

```
function findElementRecursion (inputId, currentElement) {
  if (currentElement.id == inputId) {
    return true;
  }

  if (!currentElement.children) return false;
  var numChildren = currentElement.children.length;
  if (numChildren > 0) {
    for (var i in currentElement.children) {
      var currentChild = currentElement.children[i];
      console.log(currentChild);
      if (findElementRecursion(inputId, currentChild)) return true;
    }
  }   
return false;
}
```

Notice that you also have to check if the element actually has children

Answer (score 0):

From the initial code,

```
function findElementRecursion (inputId, currentElement) {
    if (currentElement.id == inputId) {
        return true;
    }
    var numChildren = currentElement.children.length;
    if (numChildren > 0) {
        for (i=0; i<numChildren; i++) {
            var currentChild = currentElement.children[i];
            console.log(currentChild);
            return findElementRecursion(inputId, currentChild);
        }
    }   
    return false;
}
```

The problem was I was returning too early and breaking out of the loop after only checking the first element of each currentElement.

```
function findElementRecursion (inputId, currentElement) {
    if (currentElement.id == inputId) {
        return true;
    }
    var numChildren = currentElement.children.length;
    if (numChildren > 0) {
        for (i=0; i<numChildren; i++) {
            var currentChild = currentElement.children[i];
            console.log(currentChild);
            if (findElementRecursion(inputId, currentChild)) return true;
        }
    }   
    return false;
}
```

However, the function still returns false when it should return true. That's because I didn't set `i` as local variable. It should have been `var i` so it is contained in each local environment.

```
function findElementRecursion (inputId, currentElement) {
    if (currentElement.id == inputId) {
        return true;
    }
    var numChildren = currentElement.children.length;
    if (numChildren > 0) {
        for (var i=0; i<numChildren; i++) {
            var currentChild = currentElement.children[i];
            console.log(currentChild);
            if (findElementRecursion(inputId, currentChild)) return true;
        }
    }   
    return false;
}
```

Everything is good!